# How are these wires bonded?

Tags: connector, soldering, adhesives

This connector is from a Chevy Cobalt, but I think the question is more about electrical technology than automotive stuff.  Feel free to close, if I'm wrong.

One of the (5) wires attached to the lug (below) does not have good continuity.  Bonding to the lug appears to be made with the mesh-like material at the right end of the neck (below).  Questions:

1. Does anyone recognize this material?
2. Would it be compromised if I was to solder the exposed wires in the area between that mesh and the strain-relief tabs?  (Whether soldering is even a good idea is another matter.)

[image]

Comment: That connector is toast... recommend cutting all five of those wires back an inch or so and replacing all of it.  Possibly with two or three ring connectors, space permitting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks like an ultrasonic weld.  I'm not sure if soldering onto the weld nugget would compromise it but soldering onto terminals that are not designed for it is not recommended.

Edit: also, I don't recommend soldering at all in this application since it will wick up into the strands of the wire (exacerbated by the need to heat a huge copper lug) and create weak points vulnerable to vibration.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the other 'arm' of the lug and remove the wires. Trim the insulation off each for a short distance (1 cm); join all 5 wires and a 6th together and put the 6th in the lug and crimp.